# Tortoise CVS icons not visible in Win 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, icons, version-control, cvs

I'm running Tortoise CVS 1.10.10 (with CVS NT 2.5.03) on Win 7 x64, and my folder overlay icons won't appear.

I don't remember when this happened, however I've a colleague running the same setup (also Win 7, x64) and his icons appear just fine.

I've tried installing the latest release of Tortoise CVS (1.12.4) however this version produced a missing iconv-x-x-x.dll error when trying to run 'cvs.exe' commands (and didn't display any overlay icons either).

I have set the overlay icons setting in Tortoise CVS preferences to no avail.  I can check in and checkout just fine.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you reboot after installing it? Because for whatever reason, it's really serious when it says to reboot. I had the same problem and rebooting fixed it for me. (I only reboot otherwise when a security update forces me to)

Comment: Thanks to paradroid's response regarding a conflict with DropBox, a quick Google revealed the problem could result from Windows' limited number of icon overlay slots.

This article suggests a solution for running DropBox and Tortoise in parallel by relegating infrequently used Tortoise CVS icons to the bottom of the list (actually it is one of the comments that suggests this):
http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/10/26/fixing-icon-overlays-for-dropbox-tortoisesvn.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this problem as well.  It turned out to be because I had Dropbox installed on the same machine, so I install Dropbox on a server instead now.

This problem can probably be caused by other programs that use icon overlays, as Windows can only allow a limited number of these from third-party programs.

Answer (score 5):

This is the first search result that comes up in google when I search for "tortoisecvs icons win7 64".  So even though it's an old post, I wanted to add another solution.  The accepted answer says to uninstall DropBox.  I don't have DropBox, but I still get no icon overlays in 64-bit applications (I do see the overlays if I use file dialogs in 32-bit applications).

A hunt through the TortoiseCVS bug tracker yielded a comment that includes this link: [How to Fix Missing TortoiseSVN File Status Icons in Windows](http://www.sitepoint.com/missing-tortoisesvn-file-status-overlay-icons/)

> [...]  navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
>
> Export the branch as a .reg file — this will allow you to restore the old settings should anything go wrong.
>
> You will see the Tortoise and other icon overlay identifiers as sub-branches. You can delete unnecessary icon overlay types by right-clicking a branch and selecting Delete [...]

I know it says TortoiseSVN, but it's the same principle.  There's a mention in there about how DropBox creates overlays, so I would say this is a more complete solution.

Cheers =)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, installing Tortoise CVS in XP SP3 compatibility mode worked. I tried all registry editing with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to uninstall and re-install Tortoisecvs 1.12.5 and the icons started working...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by uinstalling Google drive.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The folders/files in CVS check-out root folders are set to read-only. When I unset read-only, the icons shows up. However, each time I commit newer files, I have to do this again and again. I didn't find permanent solution up to now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a priority in registry, read link:

http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2015/03/22/managing-overlay-icons-for-dropbox-and-tortoisesvn-and-tortoisegit/

Comment: Could you please give some details as to how this answers the question.  A link-only answer isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.